# How do you debug an Android "FirebaseFirestoreException: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Quota exceeded" issue

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

In my Android app, I'm getting an exception:

```
W: Caused by: com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Quota exceeded.
```

But when I go to the console page, the app is well under the limits.  And by well under, I mean numbers like "Firestore Read Operations 
0.00034 of 0.05 Million Ops" - not even close.

How do I get more information from Firestore, either in the app or on the console, about exactly what limits I'm exceeding?

I'm using:

```
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

as I do know Firestore can be exceed quota by API Calls.
Let says i have 1000 documents in a collection then I had fetch the data again and its not count 1 but count 1000 so its can exceed quota easily.
And u can read only 50K/day for all devices so if you have 50 users read 1000 documents quota will be exceeded real quick.
Be careful[image]

Comment: The problem is that the console says I haven't come close to exceeding any limits, and I'm seeing logcat messages saying "Quota exceeded."  One of them is wrong.  How do I tell which one, and _which_ limit?

Comment: @JamesMoore I guess now is on beta so console didn’t display properly anyway how many api calls in console that u got?